# Android Google Plus Sign in (Online Docs vs Auth Sample in Google Play Services Sample)

Tags: android, google-plus, google-api-client

There is a major difference between the following guides for Google Plus sign in for Android:

a) Online documentation at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

b) QuickStart Example at https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android (which is referenced from https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android)

c)The Samples found at /extras/google-play-services/samples/auth (which is mentioned at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html)

Honestly I am ultimately confused as to which is the proper way of going about things. They seem to all end up at the same result. (Minus a few bugs here and there in some, depending on builds).

Is there a clear and concise way to go about this or is it a free for all on deciding?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, the codes are very different . I am planning to go ahead with the quick start code. Please share your insights

Comment: @Akhil l ive gone away from the SDK entirely and follow my third example which makes a http call instead